# Geodesy library for C#

Tags: c#, wgs84

Since i could not get an exact answer on this question [Distance of wgs point from a wgs defined line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045544/distance-of-wgs-point-from-a-wgs-defined-line-segment) , does anyone know of a geodesy library that encompasses functionality for calculations while developing a GPS application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of open source projects on codeplex, [DotSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/) and [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/). A lot of spatial functions are implemented in their libraries. If you could use any spatial database such as [Spatialite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/) or [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) then you will be able to perform a lot of spatial operations really quickly and without any hassle.

Comment: DotSpatial is split into smaller libraries so if you like you can only use the Topology or Projection libraries that are needed to do these calculations, without using the whole framework.