# Match coordinate to closest start and end latitude/longitude pairs

Tags: algorithm, sqlite, maps, coordinates, gis

I'm trying to match a latitude and longitude pair to a road segment that has a start and end latitude and longitude. All of the formulas I've been able to find query by the closest match to a single latitude and longitude, but not to a pair. I suppose one option is to get the average, or center of the segment, but this is not ideal. I'm querying this in SQLLite since my data is in GeoPackage format, but if anyone even has a formula to use I can translate that to SQLLite.

[image: Here is a poorly drawn example of the segmentation of the roads, each line has its own start and end latitude/longitude coordiantes]

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me what your idea of a correct solution is - maybe adding the coordinate you are trying to match to your drawing would help.  If it is a nearest point to line algorithm you are looking for then I suggest [Distance from point to line on Earth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7804061/1124740) as a starting place. If it is a more database-y solution then some of the links from  [How to find the nearest point by using PostGIS function?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/31094/25830) might help

Answer (score 0):

Hmm interesting. Conceptually, and without considering performance, would the following work? (consider this untested pseudo):

```
SELECT
    MIN(ABS(lon_field - :lon1)) AS start_lon,
    MIN(ABS(lat_field - :lat1)) AS start_lat,
    MIN(ABS(lon_field - :lon2)) as end_lon,
    MIN(ABS(lat_field - :lat2)) AS end_lat;
```

Comment: Hey Ewan, sorry if I didn't explain the question well enough. The data I have is already divided into road segments that have their own start and end latitude and longitude pairs. I want to find the closest road segment given a singular latitude and longitude point.